# Font Weights for System Fonts Messed Up in Multiple Web Browsers

Tags: safari, font, web-browser

[image]

I've noticed this effect in multiple web browsers and it seems to have come on suddenly. I've tried booting into safe mode, changing my display settings, and disabling all browser extensions.

Here's an example on Facebook where the semi bold font looks much bolder than normal. I've seen other sites which use the default system-ui font where bold fonts appear less bold than they should as well.

It appears to be related to font-smoothing, as I can move a browser from my 4k display to my Macbook Retina and the issue resolves.

However, I've tried disabling and resetting font-smoothing with TinkerTool and that does not resolve the issue. I typically have had font-smoothing on without the issue.

Any ideas how to fix this? I'm running Sonoma 14.3 and have the same issue in the latest Arc, Safari and Brave browsers.